# Weak* subseries convergent implies norm convergent?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a Banach space and $X^{*}$ is separable. Suppose that $\sum x_{n}^{*}$ is a series in $X^{*}$ which has the property that every subseries $\sum x_{n_{k}}^{*}$ converges weak*. Show that $\sum x_{n}^{*}$ converges in norm.
[Hint: Every $x^{**}\in X^{**}$ is the weak* limit of a sequence in $X$.]

I know the hint basically follows from Goldstine's theorem that $B_{X}$ is weak* dense in $B_{X^{**}}$ and from the fact that the weak* topology on $B_{X^{**}}$ is metrizable by the assumption that $X^{*}$ is separable. But I can't figure out how to use the hint.

Comment: Let $x^\star$ be the weak*-limit and suppose the series does not converge in norm to $x*$. This gives you an $\epsilon>0$, a subseries $\sum x_{n_k}^\star$, and some $x_k \in X$ with $||x_k||=1$ and with $\epsilon \leq |(x^\star-\sum x_{n_k}^\star)(x_k)|$. Now $(x_k)_k$ has a weak*-convergent subsequence in $X^{**}$ and you can apply the hint.

Comment: Is the $x^{*}$ at the beginning the weak* limit of some subseries or is it the weak* limit of the original series $\sum x_{n}^{*}$? Also, at the end you got that $(x_{k})$ has a weak* convergent subsequence in $X^{**}$, but how do I apply the hint to that?

Comment: $x^\star$ is the limit of the original series, the only possible norm limit. But I haven't explicitly used the hint nor the fact that $X$ is Banach. And I thought that equicontinuity of the $\sum x_{n_k}^\star$ was enough, but we need weak equicontinuity. Maybe we haven't thought about this strange "every subseries"-property.

Comment: Do we even know that the original series has a weak* limit?

Comment: The series itself is a subseries. Please define what you mean with "every subseries".

Comment: Yes, you're right.